# NHibernate Mapping Attributes + Spring

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, spring.net

I'm working on a C# .NET project in which I am mapping my classes to the tables in my database with NHibernate. I need to use NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes and transactions to be configured by Spring.

The fact is that Spring 1.3.0 provides a sample project called "Spring.Data.NHibernate.Northwind" that almost provides all the functionalities and the architecture that I want to implement in my project. The problem is that this sample project uses xml mapping files instead of attributes to map the classes, and as of today I've not been able to found any way to make the sample project work with attributes mapping.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to specify why it's not working out. Are you getting certain errors? At StackOverflow, it's best to ask specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I actually found a solution, there: [Spring.NET forum](http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?t=3502&highlight=Nhibernate+Mapping+Attributes)